# Iterate and append faster through millions of dictionnaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, elasticsearch, optimization

I'm writing a script to handle millions of dictionnaries from many files of 1 million lines each.
The main interest of this script is to create a json file and send it to Elasticsearch bulk edit.

What I'm trying to do is to read lines from called "entity" files, and in those entities, I have to find their matched addresses in "sub" files (for sub-entities). But my problem here, is that the function which should associate them, take REALLY too much time to do a single iteration... But after trying to optimize it as much as possible, the association still insanely slow.

So, just to be clear about the data structure:

- Entities are object like Persons : an id, an unique_id, a name, list of postal addresses, list of email addresses :
  `{id: 0, uniqueId: 'Z5ER1ZE5', name: 'John DOE', postalList: [], emailList: []}`
- Sub-entities are object referenced as differents types of addresses (mail, postal, etc ..) : `{personUniqueId: 'Z5ER1ZE5', 'Email': 'john.doe@gmail.com'}`

So, I get files content with Pandas using `pd.read_csv(filename)`.
To optimize as much as possible I've decided to handle every iterations on data using multiprocessing (working fine, even if I didn't handled RAM usage..) :

```py
## Using manager to be alble to pass my main object and update it through processes
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
main_obj = manager.dict({
   'dataframes': manager.dict(),
   'dicts': manager.dict(),
   'json': manager.dict()
})

## Just an example of how I use multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
result = pool.map(partial(func, obj=main_obj), data_list_to_iterate)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

And I have some referentials, where identifiers refers to a dict having entities name in keys and their uniqueId as value, and sub_associations is a dict where we have sub-entities name as keys and their related collection as value :

```
sub_associations = {
   'Persons_emlAddr': 'postalList',
   'Persons_pstlAddr': 'emailList'
}
identifiers = {
   'Animals': 'uniqueAnimalId',
   'Persons': 'uniquePersonId',
   'Persons_emlAddr': 'uniquePersonId',
   'Persons_pstlAddr': 'uniquePersonId'
}
```

This said, now, I experienced a big issue in my function to get sub-entities, for my entity:

```
for key in list(main_obj['dicts'].keys()):
        main_obj['json'][key] = ''
        with mp.Pool() as stringify_pool:
            res_stringify = stringify_pool.map(partial(convert_to_json, obj=main_obj, name=key), main_obj['dicts'][key]['records'])
            stringify_pool.close()
            stringify_pool.join()
```

Here is where I call my issued function. I feed it with keys I have in my `main_obj['dicts']`, where keys are just entities filename (Persons, Animals, ..),  and `my main_obj['dicts'][key]` is a list of dict where `main_obj['dicts'][key] = {name: 'Persons', records: []}` where records is the list of entities dicts I need to iterate on.

```
def convert_to_json(item, obj, name):
    global sub_associations
    global identifiers
    
    dump = ''
    
    subs = [val for val in sub_associations.keys() if val.startswith(name)]
    if subs:
        for sub in subs:
            df = obj['dataframes'][sub]
            
            id_name = identifiers[name]
            sub_items = df[df[id_name] == item[id_name]].to_dict('records')
            
            if sub_items:
                item[sub_associations[sub]] = sub_items
            else:
                item[sub_associations[sub]] = []
    
    index = {
        "index": {
            "_index": name,
            "_id": item[identifiers[name]]
        }
    }
            
    dump += f'{json.dumps(index)}\n'
    dump += f'{json.dumps(item)}\n'
    
    obj['json'][name] += dump
    
    return 'Done'
```

Does someone could have an idea about what could be the main issue ? And how I could change it to make it faster ?
If you need any additionnal information.. If I haven't been clear on some things, feel free.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: This really sounds like you are making your own database from scratch...  That said, why don't you create 1 dictionary of the entities, with the unique ID as a key and 1 dictionary of the sub-entities with the same key?  And why get the `pandas` involved?  de-serializing `json` from many files should be really quick.

Comment: @AirSquid It's more to do benchmarks on ElasticSearch ingest performances, so I need to test the bulk edit.

Yeah, I will try it, it could be the solution !

If I used Pandas it's because it's used for Data Analysis, so I tried to see if Dataframes  could be more powerful than a simple dict.

Comment: Well, it isn't real clear what role `pandas` has here or how your data in the files is structured.  Caveat 2:  I don't use elasticsearch and it isn't clear what "ingest performance" is.  But, making data frames for large files takes some appreciable time and memory, and you don't appear to be using any pandas features other than reading and json-dumping.  If true, cut that out and just de-serialize the files directly into a single dictionaries and it should be blazingly faster.